# Python object wrapper for lxml etree?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Given lxml.etree is it possible to somehow construct an object representation of the tree, so that sub-elements can be accessed in object-like fashion (with '.' operator)?

I know lxml has a library called *objectify* but it looks like it can be only constructed given raw XML and adding new elements to the tree still requires to go through the etree-like node creation.

Ideally what I want to achieve is:

```
tree = objectify( etree_root )
print tree.somenode.get( 'attrib_name' )
tree.somenode.set( 'attrib_name', 'some_val' )
Node( tree.somenode, "somechild" )
tree.somenode.somechild.set( 'attrib', 'foo' )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have to override the `__setattribute__` respectively the `__getattribute__` operators. I guess you have to subclass the etree.Element class to achieve this.

But, on the other hand this API would also be quite impractical, since there might be multiple child-nodes with the same tag name.

To find elements you can also use XPath expressions, which correllate to your idea. The API is as follows:

```
subchild = root.find('child/subchild')
```

Comment: Not entirely impractical. With some smart tinkering you can make it useful with some types of data. You can override `__get_attribute__` in a way that if `node.childname` is referenced, it will return just to first child, but for `node.childnames (with an 's' in the end) it would return a list of them. Whether this design is really useful or not depends on your XML data.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This is actually easier than I thought.
I managed to objectify each element in a rather big XML tree (~20 ms). This allows doing things like:
  `root.child.nonexistentchild[ "attrib" ] = "hello"`
This creates a `nonexistentchild` on the fly and adds attribute `attrib` with value `hello`. Just requires overriding `__setattr__`, `__getattr__`, `__get__`, `__set__`. Then you just create an _objectified_ tree by taking each node and creating object wrapper for each sibling.

Comment: neat :) 
by any chance, is it possible toget the code from somewhere?

Comment: No, due to legal reasons, I can't do that I am afraid.
One thing to be careful about are sequences. Since when objectifying you do not assert on XSD schema, if there is one element in original XML tree, you have no way of knowing if it is part of a sequence or not. You can hack around that by providing a method to 'convert' into a sequence if required.